# Creating a dummy Visualforce page for an apex test class

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, test-setup

Im working on creating a test class for two apex classes(one is scheduled another is batch apex. The scheduled is linked to the batch apex to have it run regularly.) The issue that I am running into is in the setup() method where I need to create a dummy visualforce page and assign it to billingFormat.AcctSeed_Visualforce_PDF_Page__c (line:13). This field is a 40 character text field that references a vf page, is required, and will not take any random characters. Also I previously tried to create an emailtemplate I think since I saw that type in one of the error logs but I got a Mixed DML error on top of that.

I suppose I could use the "SeeAllData = True" route but heard that is bad practice.

Is it even possible to create a dummy visualforce page for an apex class. I have spent the last day and a half searching but only find references to visualforce controllers. Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**Bill_Creation_Test.apxc**

````
@isTest
public class Bill_Creation_Test {
    
    @testSetup static void setup(){

        
            
        // Accounting Seed Billing Format
        List<AcctSeed__Billing_Format__c> bfList = new List<AcctSeed__Billing_Format__c>();
        AcctSeed__Billing_Format__c billingFormat = new AcctSeed__Billing_Format__c();
        billingFormat.AcctSeed__Default_Email_Template__c = 'Default Email Template';
        billingFormat.Name = 'PDF Name';
        billingFormat.AcctSeed__Visualforce_PDF_Page__c = ;
        bfList.add(billingFormat);
        insert bfList;
        
        
        
        //Account that is a blackbox customer and has inventory
        List<Account> customers = new List<Account>();
        Account bbcustomer = new Account();
        bbcustomer.Name = 'TestCustomer';
        bbcustomer.is_BB_Customer__c = True;
        bbcustomer.Has_Inventory__c = True;
        customers.add(bbcustomer);
        insert customers;
        
        
        //Accounting Period
        Date startDate = system.today();
        Date endDate = startDate.addMonths(1).addDays(-1);
        String dateFormat = 'yyyy-MM';
        Datetime yearAndMonth = Datetime.newInstance(startDate.year(), startDate.month(), startDate.day());
        String accountPeriodName = yearAndMonth.format(dateFormat);
        
        AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c accountingPeriod = new AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c();
        accountingPeriod.AcctSeed__Start_Date__c = startDate;
        accountingPeriod.AcctSeed__End_Date__c = endDate;
        accountingPeriod.AcctSeed__Status__c = 'Open';
        accountingPeriod.Name = accountPeriodName;
        insert accountingPeriod;
        

        
    }
    
    @isTest static void BillCreationSyncTest(){
        Blackbox_Bill_Creation_Sync test1 = new BlackBox_Bill_Creation_Sync();
        test1.execute(null);
        AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c[] aPeriod =
            [SELECT Id
            FROM AcctSeed__Accounting_Period__c
            LIMIT 1];
        System.assert(aPeriod != null);
    }
    
    @isTest static void BillCreationTest(){
        Test.startTest();

        Blackbox_Bill_Creation test2 = new Blackbox_Bill_Creation();
        Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(test2);
        
        Test.stopTest();
        AcctSeed__Billing__c[] testBill =[
            SELECT Name
            FROM AcctSeed__Billing__c
        ];
        System.assert(testBill != null);
        
    }
}```
````

Comment: How is this used? You can isolate + mock parts of your logic to avoid usage of an actual VF page

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the original VF page is used within a managed object so I don't think there is a way for me to work around it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Visualforce page outside of the test class and reference it even if you don't have (SeeAllData=True). Visualforce pages are metadata, not data.

You can reference the Visualforce Page with Page.DummyPageApiName.

UPDATE: I did a google search for your specific case, I found this page https://support.accountingseed.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015576014-Billing-Test-Class. It appears that AccountingSeed, requires that you pass in a the name of the VF page as a string, like so `billingFormat.AcctSeed__Visualforce_PDF_Page__c = 'DummyPageApiName';`

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Would I just use a SOQL query to get the reference ID of that dummy visualforce page?

Comment: I updated the answer.